# Python-style lists in Julia

Tags: python, julia

The following code acted as I expected for a Python-style list in Julia:

```
julia> list1 = [Any, 123]
2-element Array{Any,1}:
    Any
 123

julia> list1[1] = "ABC"
"ABC"

julia> list1
2-element Array{Any,1}:
    "ABC"
 123
```

However, this code did not:

```
julia> list2 = [Any]
1-element Array{DataType,1}:
 Any

julia> list2[1] = "ABC"
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type DataType
```

I was not expecting such a difference between:

```
julia> list1 = [Any, 123]
# and
julia> list2 = [Any]
```

So I tried using `any` instead of `Any`:

```
julia> list3 = [any, 123]
2-element Array{Any,1}:
    any
 123

julia> list3[1] = "ABC"
"ABC"

julia> list3
2-element Array{Any,1}:
    "ABC"
 123
```

That all worked, but then I tried:

```
julia> list4 = [any]
1-element Array{typeof(any),1}:
 any

julia> list4[1] = "ABC"
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type typeof(any)
```

What is going on with Julia's type inference that  explains why `list = [Any]` or `[any]` produce error messages, as shown above, but things work Okay if another type is added at "list" creation?

**EDIT**

Based on helpful examples in the accepted answer below, this works for creating a Python-style "list" in Julia:

```
julia> pylist = Array{Any}(nothing, 5)
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing

julia> pylist[1] = 123
123

julia> pylist[2] = 3.14
3.14

julia> pylist[3] = "ABC"
"ABC"

julia> pylist[4] = BigInt(12345)
12345

julia> pylist[5] = BigFloat(123.456)
1.234560000000000030695446184836328029632568359375e+02
```

**EDIT 2**

This is another example, but I have not been around Julia long enough to know if this is considered "Julian" or not.  Any comments from Julia experts are appreciated:

```
julia> PyList(n) = Array{Any}(nothing, n)
PyList (generic function with 1 method)
```

For others new to Julia, these two lines of code may also be helpful

```
julia> Vector{Any}(nothing, 3)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing

julia> Vector{Any}(nothing, 3) == Array{Any}(nothing, 3)
true
```

Thus, a `Vector{Any}` in the above example is just an alias for `Array{Any}`.  Here are some examples using `PyList`.

```
julia> pylst = PyList(3)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing

julia> pylst[1] = "ABC"
"ABC"  
julia> pylst[2] = 123
123
julia> pylst[3] = 3.14
3.14
julia> pylst
3-element Array{Any,1}:
    "ABC"
 123
   3.14
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[Any, 123]` does not mean "make a 1-element array of element type Any with single element 123". It means "make an array with elements Any and 123". The element type of Any is deduced from the elements given, as Any and 123 have completely unrelated types.

Similarly, `[Any]` means "make an array with single element Any". The element type is deduced as [DataType](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#Declared-Types-1).

If you want to explicitly create an array of element type Any, you can do that by putting the type in front of the literal. For example, an array of element type `Any` with single element `nothing`:

```
arr = Any[nothing]
```

There are also methods to create an array of specified size, such as

```
# 2x3 array of Any, all elements initialized to nothing
arr = Array{Any}(nothing, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Question about: "The element type of Any is deduced from the elements given."  It seems like the element type is just `Any` for both of these examples: `julia> list = [Any, "ABC"]
2-element Array{Any,1}:' and `julia> list = [Any, 123]
2-element Array{Any,1}:`

Comment: @JuliaLearner: In both of those examples, sure, because you're trying to put a DataType and an item of a completely unrelated type in the same array, but not in the `[Any]` case, where the only element has type DataType.

Comment: Yes, I did not get my examples into my original comment, had to edit.  I was thinking of 2-element arrays as shown in edited comment.

Comment: So a 1-element array of` [Any]` is not like a Python list, but a 2-element array of `[Any, 123]` is like a Python list?

Comment: If you want an array of arbitrary element type, make one explicitly rather than shoving `Any` in an array with something else.

Comment: Your final examples in the answer are very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: I also wondered why in your example that your lowercase typo in list4 = [any] does not give a syntax error, but then realized that there is a function by that name.

Comment: @Bill I wondered about the difference between `Any` and `any` in the declaration of arrays.  Are you suggesting that lowercase `any` can be considered a function or did you have something else in mind?  Thanks.

Comment: any(f, iterable) is a function that returns true the first time a function applied to the elements of an iteratable is true.

Comment: @Bill Okay, I see what you mean.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Python lists accept any type of element and are not of fixed size, so to make a new `Vector{Any}`, in Julia you just do `Any[]` (comments are in Python):

```
julia> x = Any[]        # >>> x = []
0-element Array{Any,1}  # >>> x
                        # []

julia> push!(x, 1)       # >>> x.append(1)
1-element Array{Any,1}:  # >>> x
 1                       # [1]

julia> push!(x, "2")     # >>> x.append("2")
2-element Array{Any,1}:  # >>> x
 1                       # [1, '2']
  "2"
```

Whithout `Any` Julia infers the next array comprehension to be of type `Vector{Int}`, so you wouldn't be able to push or change it's `Int` elements, with elements of other types.

```
julia> y = Any[i^2 for i in 1:3]  # >>> y = [i**2 for i in range(1, 4)]
3-element Array{Any,1}:           # >>> y
 1                                # [1, 4, 9]
 4
 9

julia> push!(y, "16")    # >>> y.append("16")
4-element Array{Any,1}:  # >>> y
 1                       # [1, 4, 9, '16']
 4
 9
  "16"
```

You can create utility functions in both languages to suit your needs.

```
julia> list() = Any[]                  # >>> list
list (generic function with 1 method)  # <type 'list'>

julia> list(n::Integer) = Vector{Any}(undef, n)  # >>> def nlist(n):
list (generic function with 2 methods)           # ...     return [None for i in range(n)]

julia> list()           # >>> list()
0-element Array{Any,1}  # []

julia> list(3)           # >>> nlist(3)
3-element Array{Any,1}:  # [None, None, None]
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```